# C# thread question why infinite loop here?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadExample
{
    public class Info
    {
        public int Counter;


        private static object _lock = new object();
        private List<Thread> ThreadList;

        public Info(int counter)
        {
            Counter = counter;

            ThreadList = new List<Thread>();

            ThreadList.Add(new Thread(ThreadBody));
            ThreadList.Add(new Thread(ThreadBody));

           ThreadList[0].Name = "t1";
           ThreadList[1].Name = "t2";

        }

        public void Start()
        {
            ThreadList.ForEach(t => t.Start(t.Name));
        }

        public void ThreadBody(object name)
        {
            while (Counter != 20)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    Counter++;

                    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} : the value of the counter is {1}", name.ToString(), Counter);
                }
            }



        }

    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ThreadExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Info info = new Info(0);
            info.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

if the lock is just lock counter ++
  lock (_lock)
                    {
                        Counter++;
                     }
         I don't have an infinite loop, but if the lock is like in example, it run infinite loop

Comment: Not sure I understand what exactly you are asking. Any chance you can elucidate further?

Comment: You need to provide more context.  The behavior you are seeing and what you have attempted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be that when `Counter` gets to 19  both threads enter the loop and it ends up getting incremented to 21 before they test the value again.

You'll need to hold the lock while reading the value of `Counter`.  A double check of `Counter` might be adequate (re-read it again inside the `while` loop while holding the lock).  However, I'm not sure about this because my head just can't keep track of all the details of various threading memory models between native, .NET, Java, and whatever.  Even on .NET the ECMA model is apparently different than what MS guarantees for their CLR (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx and http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,543d89ad-8d57-4a51-b7c9-a821e3992bf6.aspx).  For more details on why double-checking might or might not work, search for "double checked locking" - there's an awful lot of complexity behind something that apparently should be simple.

For example, here's snippet of a run on my machine:

```
Thread t1 : the value of the counter is 1
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 2
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 3
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 4
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 5
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 6
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 7
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 8
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 9
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 10
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 11
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 12
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 13
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 14
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 15
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 16
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 17
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 18
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 19
Thread t2 : the value of the counter is 20
Thread t1 : the value of the counter is 21
Thread t1 : the value of the counter is 22

... Thread t1 never stops ...
```

You'll notice that `t2` stops once it gets `Counter` to 20, but the `t1` doesn't notice that.  It's already entered the loop (or decided to enter the loop) thinking that `Counter` is 1 (or maybe 2 or something else - just not 20).

Comment: I concur - this is most likely the problem.

Comment: Even if only one thread doesn't hit this until 21, it will continue "forever".

Comment: so the solution is to net the 'while' statement inside the 'lock' statement

Comment: @Robert: Or, better yet, use <20 instead of !=20

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your line here:

```
while (Counter != 20)
```

Since you're locking around the increment to counter, at some point, `Counter` can equal 19.  Both threads can do the check, then increment counter internally, making it 21 before the threads check again.

That being said, even if the two threads don't hit that at the same time, one thread may see the 20 and stop, while the other thread has a value of 21 when that is hit, and the loop will continue forever.

Your "fix" (locking just the increment) doesn't really fix it, btw - it just makes the error case less likely.  The reason for this is the `Console.WriteLine` call is much, much slower, so more of the processing time is happening in your lock, making it more likely that the threads increment past your condition check before they see it again.  However, this could still occur with just locking the counter increment (though it'd be more rare.)

You could easily correct this by having a more flexible condition, such as:

```
 while (Counter < 20)
```

This will cause the threads to exit as soon as it hits 20 *or higher*.

Comment: How about i Just lock Counter ++. lock (_lock) { Counter++; } How about Use nterlocked.Increment(ref counter)

Comment: @retide: As long as you check for `Counter != 20`, you run the chance of one thread running forever, since the "other" thread can increment it to 21.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is written, it's possible for both threads to increment `Counter` before their respective `while` clause gets evaluated. In that case, `Counter` can go from `19` to `21` before the next `while` is hit.

Try refactoring your loop into something like:

```
while (true) {
    lock (_lock) {
        Counter++;
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} : the value of the counter is {1}",
            name.ToString(), Counter);
        if (Counter >= 20) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```